# KVO notifications of app delegate stop unexpectedly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing

I have a key in my app delegate that I listen for changes using the following code:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myKey" options:0 context:nil];
```

After some time though, the app delegate stops responding to changes to `myKey`. Why does this happen?

Comment: Please be more specific. What's the key? Under what circumstances do the observations stop?

Comment: Are you sure that the observed value is still being updated at that time. You could try NSLogging in getter method just in case you're barking at the wrong tree.

Comment: Would you post some more of your code?